# VBA code only deletes row when run in debug mode

Tags: excel, vba, rows

Im having trouble deleting Rows when running the code not in debug mode. I put stars next to the line giving me a problem. Works in debug mode but not normally running the code. Any help? I have tried using doevent but in the beginning of the for loop but that didnt work.

```
Public Sub ItemUpdate(ByVal startRow As Integer, ByVal endRow As Integer, ByVal itemCol As String, ByVal statusCol As String, ByVal manuPNCol As String)
Dim orgSheet As Worksheet
Dim commonSheet As Worksheet
Dim partDesCol As String
Dim partDes As String
Dim vendorColNumber As Integer
Dim vendorColLetter As String
Dim manuPN As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim replaceRnge As Range
Set orgSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

partDesCol = FindPartDesCol()

Set commonSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Common Equipment")

For counter = startRow To endRow
'Get part description value
partDes = Range(partDesCol & counter).Value
'Delete row of empty cells if there is any

If partDes = "" Then
'deleteing empty row
orgSheet.Rows(counter).Delete    '************************** Only works in                     
 debug mode.
endRow = endRow - 1
If counter < endRow Then
    counter = counter - 1
Else
    Exit For
End If

Else

manuPN = Range(manuPNCol & counter).Value
'Search for user part in common sheet
Set rangeFind = commonSheet.Range("1:200").Find(partDes, lookat:=xlWhole)
If rangeFind Is Nothing Or partDes = "" Then
Debug.Print "Part " & partDes & " not found in Common Equipment"
'MsgBox "Part " & partDes & " not found in Common Equipment"
'Now check if manuPN is in common equipment
Set rangeFind = commonSheet.Range("1:200").Find(manuPN, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If rangeFind Is Nothing Or partDes = "" Then
    Debug.Print "PartNumber " & manuPN & " not found in Common Equipment"
    'Now check if vendor value of item is empty
    'Get vendor col
    vendorCol = FindSearchCol()
    If orgSheet.Range(vendorCol & counter).Value = "" Then
    'Copy and paste manufact. data to vendor
    'converting from letter column to number and visa versa
    vendorColNumber = Range(vendorCol & 1).Column
    ManuColTemp = vendorColNumber - 2
    ManuPNColTemp = vendorColNumber - 1
    VendorPNColTemp = vendorColNumber + 1
    ManuCol = Split(Cells(1, ManuColTemp).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
    manuPNCol = Split(Cells(1, ManuPNColTemp).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
    VendorPNCol = Split(Cells(1, VendorPNColTemp).Address(True, False), "$")    
(0)
    orgSheet.Range(ManuCol & counter & ":" & manuPNCol & counter).Copy     Range(vendorCol & counter & ":" & VendorPNCol & counter)

End If
Else
'Copy new data from common equipment and paste in place of old data
'Get value of status
If statusCol <> "error" Then
    orderStatus = orgSheet.Range(statusCol & counter).Value
End If

commonSheet.Rows(rangeFind.Row).EntireRow.Copy
orgSheet.Range(itemCol & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

If statusCol <> "error" Then
    orgSheet.Range(statusCol & counter).Value = orderStatus
End If

End If

Else
'Copy new data from common equipment and paste in place of old data
'Get value of status
If statusCol <> "error" Then
    orderStatus = orgSheet.Range(statusCol & counter).Value
End If

commonSheet.Rows(rangeFind.Row).EntireRow.Copy
orgSheet.Range(itemCol & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

If statusCol <> "error" Then
    orgSheet.Range(statusCol & counter).Value = orderStatus
End If

End If
End If
Next counter

'call renumber item numbers
Call NumberItems(0, 0, 0, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: "only works in debug" is often associated with not fully defining all of your range references.  Start by making sure every single call to Range/Cells has a qualifying worksheet reference.

Comment: Have you checked what your `FindPartDesCol` function is returning?

Comment: Tim Williams, I went through and fixed all my references and it still doesn't work.

Comment: YowE3K, yes that just returns a column, that part of the code works fine. There are no errors it just doesnt run normally only in debug mode. So i feel like Tim Williams is more on the right track here. But i still cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to step backwards through your range.  When you step forward, as you are doing, the counter will skip a row whenever you delete a row:

```
For counter = startRow To endRow
```

Change to

```
For counter = endRow To startRow Step -1
```

Also, you should declare `endRow` and `startRow` as data type `Long`.  The range of `Integer` will not cover all the rows in an Excel worksheet; and also VBA is said to convert Integers to Longs when doing the math anyway.

Comment: I get your point but that is why I have this code: If counter < endRow Then counter = counter - 1 Else Exit For End If                            Also I changed my integers to longs, thanks for the heads up. But still didnt fix the problem.